# Не работает OnMouseDown Unity

Tags: unity3d

Не вызывается **OnMouseDown** при нажатии на объект. *Коллайдер стоит*, триггер ставил/убирал. Объект в canvas, image.
Я пробовал через:

`void IPointerDownHandler.OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)`

Но мне нужен не только клик, мне нужен **OnMouseEnter**, **OnMouseExit**. А их так не сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Причём тут коллайдеры и триггеры, если речь о `UI`? Значение имеет только размер `RectTransform` и `RaycastTarget` на `Image`.

Прописать интерфейсы после `MonoBehaviour` не забыл? Вангую, забыл.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(name+".OnPointerDown");
    }
    
    public void OnPointerEnter (PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(name+".OnPointerEnter");
    }

    public void OnPointerExit (PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(name".OnPointerExit");
    }
}
```

Comment: ни разу не использовал интерфейсы, но спасибо!